# Github Anonymous Commit history

Tags: github

I have a github repo from a few years ago that had 247 commits and 5 contributors. However the majority of commits from one of those contributors wasn't from github, rather via a Git Bash CLI that I would push from more or less anonymously.

**Problem:**
The graph view in github is only showing the commits from registered Github users (only 4 shown) - so a total of 15 commits are being shown and the other 232 commits are missing.

I want to be able to view the commits in the *Graph View* as they include **all** of the commits (all 247) - including the ones I pushed anonymously.

---

**# of Commits shown:**
[image: Total Commits]

**Only Commits by Registered Users:**
[image: Not Full Amount]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Github calculates users based on email address.

So if you add that wildcats.unh.edu address to your user account on Github, those commits should be attributed to you.